# Deleting large portions of shapefile

Tags: qgis

I'm have a huge shapefile and I'm trying to delete large portions of it. I can't seems to do it in the edit mode. Can someone please walk me through this process? I'm using QGIS 1.8.

Comment: `"I can't seems to do it in the edit mode"` What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, figured it out. I had posted this question awhile back and got it answered. I haven't touched QGIS in awhile so it was a little fuzzy for me.

I couldn't do it when I toggled into editing mode. I realize that you have to go into edit mode, VIEW > SELECT > SELECT FEATURE BY ... and then hit the X button.